# Filtering a model's ManyToMany field with __in=[somelist] produces zero results when it should produce several

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I haven't found a solution online to this--I can't be the first person attempting this.

Here's my model structure:

```
class TopModel(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()

class MiddleModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(TopModel)

class LowerModel(model.Model):
    middleParent = models.ForeignKey(MiddleModel)
    topParent = models.ForeignKey(TopModel, related_name="ref_to_top_parent")
    topmodel_refs = models.ManyToMany(TopModel, related_name="ref_to_other_tops")
```

I need to filter by some weird querying. I use the MiddleModel to filter the Top Model twice--you'll see.

So I'm making 2 query sets:

```
currentMidMod = MiddleModel.objects.get(pk=1)
firstQuerySet = currentMidMod.topmodel_set.all()

secondMidMod = MiddleModel.objects.get(pk=2)
secondQuerySet = secondMidMod.topmodel_set.all()
```

Then I filter the 1st:

```
firstQuerySet = firstQuerySet.filter(type__contains="somevalue")
```

Then I filter the 2nd:

```
secondQuerySet = secondQuerySet.filter(type__contains="test") #produces a count() of 10
#Grab a valueset of the pks
compareList = list(secondQuerySet.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

Then here is where the issue occurs:

```
newQuerySet = firstQuerySet.filter(ref_to_top_parent__topmodel_refs__in=compareList)

newQuerySet.count() #equals 0 when I know it should equal 5
```

So I'm trying to filter my first queryset by all of its LowerModel reverse foreignkeys by those LowerModels ManyToMany list of keys back to TopModels by comparing it with a list of pk values in the values list I create

It never finds matching 'pks' even though I can manually look through phpAdmin and find the matches myself

I'm dying. Please help!

EDIT: when trying to query a single PK rather than a list--it works fine e.g.

```
newQuerySet = firstQuerySet.filter(ref_to_top_parent__topmodel_refs__pk=74956)
```

When trying to compare that ManyToMany field to a list() of values(that includes '74956') it doesn't find any matches--it should at least be finding '74956' in the values_list I imagine.

Comment: What's the `count()` in `firstQuerySet`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter--in reality it's roughly 112,000 where the 2nd queryset is ~500

The issue is that the LowerModel has a ManyToMany relation to TopModels--and I need to confusingly filter out TopModels by comparing a reverse look up'd ManyToMany field to a list of values. I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: Well, it would matter if it were 0.

Comment: touché lol! it would matter if it were zero

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to make any assumptions about what debugging steps you've taken already. Have you already looked at the contents of `compareList`?

Comment: Yes--compareList is filled with the pk values I used to do my manual checking in the php sql admin.

Edit: The ManyToMany field absolutely contains pk values that are in this list--I'm worried that because it's a reverse foreign key leading into a ManyToMany that it's not going to work

Comment: Add `_id` to this line `newQuerySet = firstQuerySet.filter(ref_to_top_parent__topmodel_refs__in=compareList)` Like: `newQuerySet = firstQuerySet.filter(ref_to_top_parent__topmodel_refs_id__in=compareList)`

Comment: I tried both 'id__in' and 'pk__in' 

Also in your code it should be 'topmodel_refs__id__in=compareList'  -- I tried it with a single underscore before id for good measure, but it errored.

Thanks for the help as well!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the problem is. Have you checked to make sure that the entries are being added in the intermediate table for the ManyToMany field?

Comment: @CoryMadden I did another test run and made an edit. It's definitely working if I query an entire ManyToMany field of values against a single pk #  -- but if I try and compare a ManyToMany field with a values_list() --it is not finding any matches--when that sole pk value I provided is IN that list of values.

Comment: @CoryMadden  -- you were right with your last comment. I had thought I had checked thoroughly the values in that intermediate table--I did not. I kept looking at the wrong table apparently like an a**hole. If you want to post that comment as an answer, I'll give you the answer. Essentially I was comparing a list of values(which WERE right) to a table of wrong values because of another error in my code I found.

Comment: Hey! Awesome! I'm glad I could help. Sure, it's always nice to get the extra points for an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments on the original question, the entries were not being created in the intermediary table for the ManyToMany relationship. I just want internet points! :)